# is keras Bidirectional LSTM when return_sequences=false equivalent to [forward pass + single step backward]?

Tags: keras, lstm, bidirectional

I know how `Bidirectional()` work when `return_sequences=True` :

`model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True)`

but what im confused at is:

when `return_sequences=false` in `LSTM`  , there is **no output at each timestep**
to be combined , so how this line work?:

`model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=False)))`

`model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20)))`

for example in [this code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/ad578c4c19444af9d1f0e0d51a8283eb0db1a264/examples/imdb_bidirectional_lstm.py#L38) from keras team (note that LSTM `return_sequences=False` by default)

my Question is:

is it correct to say when `return_sequences=False` , `Bidirectional()` act like this:

output of **forward pass** of `LSTM` + "**a single time step**" in **backward direction**

so it is effectively a forward pass of `LSTM(x1...xn)` + single step `LSTM(xn)`

am i right?

=========================================================

Update:

i think it find the answer but im not sure.

when `return_sequences=False` there is **no intermediate output at each timestep**

so a **"complete forward pass"** + **"complete backward pass"** should be combined.

i.e. the last output of forward + last output of backward

`LSTM(x1...xn)` + `LSTM(xn...x1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in your update is correct.

When return_sequences=True, an output is generated for each timestep. So if there are 5 LSTM Cells in your layer, there will be 5 outputs, one per cell.

When return_sequences=False, only the last output of the forward pass (located at timestep T-1) AND the last output of the backward pass (located at timestep 0) are returned.

In both cases, the outputs are merged in some defined way, e.g concat, sum, etc